# Unable to view collections or Projects in TFS

Tags: tfs

I am given access to TFS but I am unable to access any projects or team rooms. I constantly get to see "No Collections exist or you do not have enough permissions". I am unable to view my permission level. Is there a way to do so? Particularly can I see my permission level in command prompt?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you not able to view them in Visual Studio or Web portal or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to view permission yourself when you meet below **prerequisites**:

- You must have a project to connect to.
- You must be a member of the **Project Valid Users Group** or
  **Project Collection Valid Users** Group to view permissions.

More detail steps show how to do this please refer this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/view-permissions?view=azure-devops).

---

In your case, first ask your admin to double check your permission settings. Make sure you didn't be added in any group which deny the corresponding permission. In TFS, deny trumps allow.

Besides also check the "**Access Level**" that the Admin assigned to your account.

When your account is assigned as "[Stakeholder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/get-started-stakeholder?view=azure-devops)", you can only access to "Work" section, cannot access to "Code". If you want the access to "Code", you need to ask your Admin to change the access level of your account.